# I can't get the ball to bounce of my bat

Tags: java, intersection

This is my Bat and Ball X and Y --

```
    private int moveBallX = 1;
    private int moveBallY = -1;
    private int ballX = 320;
    private int ballY = 220;
    private double batX = 240;
    private int batY = 450;
```

Here is the methods to draw the ball --

Rectangle Ball = new Rectangle(ballX, ballY, 15, 15);

```
    public void drawBall(Graphics g){

    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillOval(Ball.x , Ball.y, 15, 15);

}
```

And here is my collision code that will not repel the ball if it hits the Bat inside of the move method I have. (Fwi I'm leaving out the Ball and Bat moving code from this method as I am only having trouble with this part)

```
 public void move(){

    if(Bat.intersects(Ball)){

        moveBallY = -moveBallY;

    }
 }
```

I have assigned Ball.x and Ball.y to moveBallX and moveBallY with this code --

```
    Ball.x += moveBallX;
    Ball.y += moveBallY;
```

And here is the code where the move and draw method is called --

```
public void run() {
      init();
      while(true){

          thread.currentThread();
            try {
               Thread.sleep(10);
             } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }

        draw();
        move();

    }
}
```

And the draw method --

```
public void draw(){
    buffer = window.canvas.getBufferStrategy();

    if(buffer == null){
        window.canvas.createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }

    g = buffer.getDrawGraphics();
    g.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    //draw below

    drawBall(g);
    drawBat(g);
    drawBricks(g);

    //end here

    buffer.show();
    g.dispose();

}
```

Comment: Well, what is the value of Ball and what is the value of Bat?  Seems like an easy thing to debug.  Are we to assume this is in c#?

Comment: No this is Java. Would it be easier if I send you all the code?

Comment: What do you mean the Value? Is what I posted above not related to the value?

Comment: Bat and Ball look like a rectangles, so if the question is why the intersect isn't working, it should be easy for you to check the values of Bat and Ball.  Your posted code doesn't show any information for the Bat object, or where you call this move method.

Comment: @LarsTech I have posted the move method and the draw method and where it is called